# Flutter adding an item each x time on sliver list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to show an ad after each the 6th post of my sliver list, now I'm doing the below approach and it's working but it's replacing a post within an ad not actually adding it.

```dart
SliverList(
   delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, i) {
      if ( i != 0 && i % 6 == 0 ) { // this replacing each 6th on the list not adding new
         // return ad widget
      }
      // return list item
   },
   childCount: dynamicListLength
)
```

Comment: change i % 6 = 0 to i % 6 == 0

Comment: sorry about that it's a typo on the question but it's already `==` on my code of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do with `ListView.builder` (it's easy to adapt it to `SliverList`):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Represents the default item
class ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  
  const ItemWidget(this.text);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text(text));    
  }
}

// Represents the ad widget
class AdWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("Ad"));    
  }
}

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  
  const Screen({this.children});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int every = 6;
    
    final int size = children.length + children.length ~/ every;
    final List<Widget> items = List.generate(size, (i) {
      if (i != 0 && i % every == 0) return AdWidget();
      return children[i - i ~/ every];
    });
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => items[i],
      itemCount: items.length,
    );  
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like that:

```dart
Screen(children: [for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) ItemWidget("$i")]);
```

Comment: it's replacing some of my data list to add the ad widget still on the listview, your code it's similar to mine the only difference is `[i - i ~/ every];`

Comment: Are you changing the item count of the ListView (e.g. `children.length + children.length ~/ every`)? If so, can you edit your question showing how you're creating the `dynamicListLength` variable?

Comment: Yes that's why it's working now probably, thanks.